# trouble with appending scores in python

Tags: python

the code is supposed to give 3 questions with 2 attempts. if the answer is correct the first try, 3 points. second try gives 1 point. if second try is incorrect, the game will end.

however, the scores are not adding up to create a final score after the 3 rounds. how do i make it so that it does that?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take a minute to read the guidelines for including a complete minimal example in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

First move `import random` to the top of the script because you're importing it every time in the loop and the score is calculated just in the last spin of the program since you empty scoreList[] every time

Comment: oh so how do i make it calculate for each loop altogether?

Comment: also, moving it to the top of the script doesn't really do much lol. it still prints the questions at random

Comment: moving it to the top doesn't effect the purpose of your program but why would you import it every time ?!
and to calculate all the score altogether move 'scoreList = []' out the loop
or debug your program with this site http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit to know exactly what your program is actually doing .